# How to set up an environment in Eclipse CDT by script per project?

Tags: c++, eclipse, environment, eclipse-cdt

I have got several projects in my workspace. I have a script which set a different environment for each project. How can i get Eclipse CDT to use this script to set up the environment instead of setting everything by hand for each project?

Thanks.

Comment: Because of the different project environment i am not able to set the environment before starting eclipse.

Answer (score 1):

You can translate your script into java, then develop a plug-in to call the API of CDT to apply the environment.

Answer (score 0):

Eclipse CDT Properties for the C/C++ Build has an "Environment" page.  You can set variables in this (per project) and either replace or append the native environment.

Right click your project and choose **Properties**
Expand the **C/C++ Build** item and choose **Environment**.  From there you can modify the properties page.

Unless you have something complicated in  your script, this could replace the need for a script altogether.  Check out the other settings in the properties page - these might help you to customize each project as you need.

Comment: I know, but there IS something complicated in my script. So i cannot setup the environment by hand.

Comment: Without anymore details on what "complicated" means, I'm not sure what else to suggest.  You might try to replace your build command with a script that calls your script and then the build command.